# Set viewport to match physical pixels

Tags: javascript, viewport

I'm trying to make the viewport exactly match the physical pixels on the screen.

The page I'm working on's HTML (which I can't change, because that would break other things using the same HTML) includes:

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

How would I make the viewport match physical pixels in javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by physical pixels ?

Comment: @Ashvin777 ...the ones on the screen? I can count them using a magnifying glass.

Comment: you can just set the direct fixed width in viewport -  content="width=100;"

Comment: @Ashvin777 Wouldn't that just set the viewport to 100?

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is layout into a larger viewport and then scale down the page until it fits into the screen.

`window.devicePixelRatio` is the number of physical pixels per CSS pixel at scale=1.

We'll first adjust the layout width that the page flows into. Since `width=device-width` is the device viewport width in CSS pixels, you want to *multiply* that by `window.devicePixelRatio` so that it's the width of the device viewport in physical pixels. Unfortunately, there's no keyword for this so you have to do it from JS:

```
// Assuming <html> has `width: 100%`.
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=' + width + ', minimum-scale= 1');
```

However, now your page is wider than the device viewport. You can probably apply the correct viewport-meta scale attributes to shrink it back down but I'd recommend using CSS transforms since they're more interoperable and have fewer quirks than viewport meta, it's likely to work better across browsers. In that case you need to now scale the page down by *dividing* by the devicePixelRatio:

```
document.documentElement.style.transform = `scale(${1 / window.devicePixelRatio})`;
document.documentElement.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
```

That will shrink your content so that 1 CSS pixel == 1 physical pixel.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks! Changing the viewport element didn't make any difference, as far as I could tell (tested in chrome). transform scale worked for shrinking the page down. I just did transform scale and setting the dom elements to devicePixelRatio times their original width and height, and that worked.

Comment: The viewport meta only works on mobile so if you're testing on a desktop you won't see any difference. The other way it might not make a difference is if your DOM elements are explicitly sized (e.g. 600px rather than 100%), or at least the root is.

Comment: Just a small correction: "minimum-scale: 1" doesn't do anything. It would do if it were "minimum-scale=1", but it actually broke the viewport scale... So it's better to just remove the "minimum-scale: 1" part and let only the width be set by javascript.

Comment: @DavidBokan you didn't respond to danielRibeiro comment, was he wrong?

Comment: He's correct and I've fixed the example - thanks!