# Mobile browsers low resolution viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, viewport

I'm facing a weird problem. I have a DIV that takes half of the available screen space and this DIV has only a Canvas Image (that I generate on the fly). I set the size of the canvas using the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` or the DIV.

```
var efisWidth = hudView.offsetWidth;
var efisHeight = hudView.offsetHeight;
```

My web page draws the canvas considering the width and height from this two properties. It looks perfect on PC as the resulting image is 1:1 to the screen resolution. But on mobile, the image is not on it's full resolution, because mobile browser informs lower resolution on this properties than the actual screen resolution.

I use an iPhone 7 Plus (1080x1920 screen) but the `offsetWidth` informs 414 instead of 1080. As a result, it renders my canvas at lower resolution, and the browser just stretches it to the actual screen resolution, but the result is a low resolution image.

If I use on viewport meta tag a `initial-scale=0.5`, the canvas is rendered using it's full resolution just like I expect, but I'm afraid to use this workaround because I don't know if other smartphones does exactly the same thing as iPhone does (viewport is half of the actual screen resolution on iphone).

[image: Example on lower resolution viewport makes the resulting image poor quality]

**Question is**: What's the best approach when I need to render a canvas on the actual screen resolution and want to avoid mobile browser to make a lower resolution viewport?

Comment: Have you included the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) in your document?

Comment: Yes I had, @Turnip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this website tells everything that I needed to know:
[iPhone Screens Demystified](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified)

In sort:

- iPhone [6,7,8] Plus native resolution is 1242x2208, not 1080x1920!
- iPhone screen resolution is actually 1080x1920! It downsamples everything from the native resolution to fit the actual screen resolution every time.
- Viewport's `device-width` constant is 414 "points" wide. This is 1/3 of the 1242 pixels of the native resolution width.
- There's a property that tells exactly the ratio of the viewport compared to the native screen resolution: It is `window.devicePixelRatio`. On iPhone [6,7,8] Plus, the value of this property is `3`, which means that the native screen resolution is 3x the viewport resolution.
- Safari makes this "low resolution" viewport so websites can know that the screen is small and adapt itself to this lower resolution.

My Canvas is rendered using the informed available screen space, which is 414 wide and ~450 tall. Then my routine renders everything inside this canvas using this as base numbers... and the result is a generated image with 1/3 of the native resolution of the screen.

To solve my problem I used [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610164/set-viewport-to-match-physical-pixels/45644115#45644115) to set the viewport width to the real native width (which is 1242). Safari will make everything fit in the screen on it's native resolution.